Long contour scribe?
The scribes that I have found/seen online are all small: a few inches. I would like one with a reach of at least twelve inches.  Will I likely need to construct one myself?
The immediate purpose is to replicate wall and fixture patterns for flooring. But I could see this being useful for other tasks.  In a pinch I'd settle for a scribe that is only eight inches since my tiles are about that width.
Update I want to be able to follow the profiles for rectangular, curved, and irregular surfaces so a Profile Gauge - which shines for rectangular outlines - is not a preferred approach.
Another update I just found a promising candidate [after dozens of searches]. It appears to be a fifteen inch rolling scribe, which is precisely what I was looking for.  https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0CXDZJ95X/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=AMWPHD38AXXSD&psc=1


There are 12 inch profile gauges.   Would that work?   Just do a section at a time.  You could make a scribe out of a stick. But they rely on hand control to stay perpendicular to the surface being scribed.  How will you do that with a very long one?

I am updating the question to explain why profile gauges won't work.  The hand control is going to come into play one way or the other most likely.

I'd consider just using a compass opened to the appropriate distance, possibly with a small spirit level attacked to make sure I  was holding it consistently.
